# Commenting to issue when commiting to Gitlab does not work

Tags: gitlab

I am running my own instance of a Gitlab-CE server with the following fairly-up-to-date specs:

- Gitlab Version  10.8.4
- Gitlab Shell 7.1.2
- Gitlab Workhorse v4.2.1

Now my problem is that when I add a message to my commits referencing an issue, there is no commit mention in the issue as there should be.

As an example:  `git commit -m "handled issue #12"` and the obligatory `git push` does not add anything to issue 12.

Any idea as to where the problem could be?

Edit: added the information that I am already pushing to the remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it: turns out that I had forgotten to change back my email adresse back to the one used in the remote repo – I had it changed locally a few weeks ago to test s.th.

So due to using my ssh key committing worked, but it showed the wrong user in my commits (which should have been a good hint for me as to what's up...) and due to that user not being a member of the project I had no access to the issues (at least that's my conclusion here).

Hope this might help anyone silly enough to run into similar issues...

Answer (score 0):

`git commit` just creates a local commit in your branch. If you want GitLab to be aware of it, you need to push it:

```
$ git push origin my-branch
```

Comment: Sorry, obviously I wasn't very clear and forgot to mention that I am pushing to the remote, edited in the post. Thanks for clarifying, but unfortunately that's not it...